# Magento 2 – default admin editor -where is settings js code?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, tinymce, editor

I want to change admin editor setting but not found config js code, please guys share me JS code path so i can change editor settings.

Comment: what you want to change? Can you please more specify?

Comment: I want to add two options - “force_br_newlines: true” and “force_p_newlines: true”

Comment: it is already there, I mean already Magento has set default `true` for both

Comment: can you please share path, i need to change more settings.